# Installation Error - D/InstallAppProgress(): Installation error code: -25

Tags: android, adt, android-build

I am trying to install my APK, which has been signed by my Production key (the same one I have always used for my app in the Play Store).

When I try to install a test build (again, signed with the production key), I can't install over the original (can install if I delete the current production build first).  I am worried that when I update my app the next time that this is going to cause issues.

I get this error (this is the only relevant line in the logcat, no other output that has anything):

```
D/InstallAppProgress(14669): Installation error code: -25
```

I have updated the ADT since building with my previous release, and generate the APK for release directly out of the IDE (using the Android Tools right-click menu from the main project).

I am not changing permissions or anything.  I have changed some internal libraries (using the new Support Lib for instance).

Comment: how are you installing it? using adb?
You need to update your manifest version to be able to overinstall.

Comment: actually, installing it from Dropbox.  I will install it from ADB, that may give me more output.

Comment: I don't think I can install over using ADB (ie.  I can only un-install, then install).  I get error [Package already exists] when trying to install when APK already exists on device (which is of course necessary for this test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the version number in your Manifest.  If the version is less than the one on the device, you will not be able to over-install.

You can install it using `adb` by using the `-r` flag.
See here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Thank you for that.  I didn't know about the -r option (which for completeness is: -r: Reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.).  This doesn't solve my problem directly, see my answer.  Thanks very much for this data point regardless.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by inconsistencies with the version number in my manifest file.

I was trying to install the new APK, that had a lower version number than the APK already installed on the device.

I increased the version number, and am able to deploy over the old version again.

Comment: Did you see my first comment on the question??

Comment: I do see that now.  I focused on the question.  Thanks regardless.  Hopefully someone else with version issues will see this answer and it will help them.